# What is special with this user agent? page keep refreshing only with this UA

Tags: ios, iphone, reactjs, safari, user-agent

I am having an issue with this UA

#### Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_4_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/47.0.2526.107 Mobile/12H321 Safari/600.1.4

Site is written in React and using query like  *?nexturl*  to navigate on access.It works fine on all other UA that i can find on simulators, but not this one.

Simply it doesn't work on my iphone6 and my ipad as well, which is hmm big issue. And if i switch to desktop UA, it works fine.
Even IOS 6,7 UA all works fine on simulate.

It is causing a looping refresh with the navigation above. No error produced, just refreshing.

Anyone have ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: I'd posit there's nothing wrong with the user-agent, but rather with the code parsing/acting on the user-agent.

Comment: @lux thx, do you have any experience on that one. It is official chrome UA on ios8. What could be generally wrong in code , specially with ios8?

Comment: I'd suggest posting the code that interacts with the UA; we won't really know what's happening without that.